# Remove Digits from Index Column Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, sql-update

I have a table that its ID has three extra digits on it, like start at 1001, 2001...n001.
I'm trying to remove those digits, but didn't find a way so far.

I need to remove this digits to match with the values at other tables.

Comment: Which data type does the column have?

Comment: What are the three extra digits?  What results do you want?  Do you have values like `02` or `1`?

Comment: well, I tried the answer below and it works, kind of. It has integer value (serial). The data came from a migration that included those 3 digits. I just need to clear it, 1001 = 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can transform `1001` to `1`, `2001` to `2`, and so on, with a simple (integer) division by `1000`, like:

```
select mycol/1000
```

Depending on the datatype of your column, you might need additional casting:

```
select mycol:int/1000
```

If you want an `update` statement:

```
update mytable set mycol = mycol / 1000
```